# int variable comparison returning a boolean value

Tags: java

I have a boolean method that is doing some error checking on a string. 
I have a int class Constant called "numWords" = 8.
I pass a string into the boolean method where I do a word count on the string using .split and .length. 
An int called "words" counts the number of words in the string. 
After this is done I want to do an if statement comparing words against numWords. 
If they are equal in number return true else false. 
I have tried == and .equals but nothing works. Any ideas?

```
public static final int numWords = 8;

boolean test = true;
String sentence = "I am a man";
test = check(sentence);

public static boolean check (String sentence) {
    boolean x = true;
    String[] s = sentence.split(" ");
    int words = s.length;

    if (words == numWords) {
        x = true;
    } 
    else {
        x = false;
    }
    return x;

}
```

I have tried == , it never evaluates to false

I have tried .equals, int cannot be dereferenced

I have tried =, doesn't compile incompatible types

What I want is if words = 8 then it equals numWords and returns true.
If words is 7 or 9 then it doesn't equal numWords and returns false.

Comment: Where do you return a `boolean`? in your `check` method? Post compilable code please.

Comment: Where is the `return` statement in your method?
If there is no `return` statement, that code will not compile.

Comment: What input are you giving?

Comment: A note: wouldn't compile as it misses a `;` here: `boolean x = true`

Comment: Why was this even downvoted? Also since OP is claiming the method is always returning `false`, we can assume he had a return statement there, but just missed in the code here.

Comment: @RohitJain I am guessing because it does not show a minimal effort to post a compilable example.

Comment: @skiwi Common. OP has shown quite a good effort at explaining what he wants to do. I've seen worst question than this. But this one is fine and shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: @skiwi:  That's not entirely a reason to downvote a question in and of itself; if it's a typographical error then it could be closed as such.  But downvoting non-compiling examples because they don't compile would lead to a *lot* of downvoted (and otherwise good) questions.

Comment: @Makoto It was just a guess as to why some downvoter had downvoted this. The question is still odd, as if he was really returning `x`, then the code would have worked...

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. You should just pass an input that has exactly `8` space separated words.

Comment: This is the subsection of a larger method doing error checking on a sentence. I apologize if I offended anyone by not adhering to forum rules. This was my first question. The reason there was no return was because I have about 4 to 5 checks I must do on the sentence. I want each check to only change the boolean if it is incorrect. So after 5 checks if x = true then it returns true. If one of the checks has changed it, it will return false. All of my other checks work except this one. I appreciate the help people have suggested.

Comment: @user3452905 No need to apologize. You haven't violated any rules. And welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making a guess that what you actually want is to return a boolean instead of assigning a boolean.

```
public static boolean check (String sentence) {

    String[] s = sentence.split(" ");
    int words = s.length;

    return words == numWords
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have valid syntax (*any* statement not having a semi-colon is invalid), and you're not actually returning anything.

Without anything to the correctness of your program, add a semi-colon after you declare and instantiate `x` (so `boolean x = true;`), and also add `return x;` to the bottom of your method.  Or, you could simply perform this:

```
return s.length == numWords;
```

No if-checks required, and it will be true if they're equivalent, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code won't compile if there is a missing colon in

```
boolean x = true;
```

Also, since your method declaration is

```
public static boolean check (String sentence)
```

you have to *return* a boolean:

```
return some_boolean;
```

The final code would be:

```
public static boolean check (String sentence) {
    String[] s = sentence.split(" ");

    return s.length == numWords;
}
```

**Note:**

The line

```
return words == numWords;
```

will return the `boolean` that is result of the comparison `s.length == numWords`.

Answer (score 0):

Make it return the number of your words, then check it outside your method if it equals your `numWords` value. Or make another method that does that.